# window.open(url).print() not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, printing, safari

I have an issue while printing in the Safari browser. When I use `window.open(url)` and try to print this newly opened URL, it tries to print a blank page.

As suggested in few other sites, I tried to set a delay of 3000ms. Like,

```
window.open(url)
setTimeout(print, 3000);
```

This tries to print the previous window and not the new tab open.
I have tried using `window.focus()` before printing. It didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

First, the `Window` object passed in the setTimeout is the one from the original page, so you should do something like

```
var popup = window.open(url);
popup.onload= function(){
    // this now refers to `popup`
    this.print()
}
```

But since you mentioned a Safari issue, I'll note that this seems to only work for normal document page (at least for HTML files) in this browser.

For documents like `data:image/...`, the Window object returned by `window.open()` doesn't have any property (at least in bugged Safari 9.1 on 10.9, didn't tried in other versions), hence you can't call the `popup.print()` method.

One way for it would be to create yourself the page and e.g for an image, append an `<img>` tag with the desired url as `src`.
It will depend on what you are trying to print though.

```js
var url = 'data:image/png;base64,...';

// you have to keep a reference of the new Window
var popup = window.open(url);

var tryToPrint = function() {
  // we have access to the window methods
  if (popup.print) {
    // call directly its print method
    popup.print()
  } else {
    // close this one
    popup.close();
    // open a new blank one
    popup = window.open('');
    // create an image
    var img = popup.document.createElement('img');
    // reproduce default Safari's styles
    img.setAttribute('style', '-webkit-user-select:none; display:block; margin:auto;');
    // once the image has loaded, we can print the page
    img.onload = function() {
      popup.print()
    };
    popup.document.body.appendChild(img);
    img.src = url;

  }
};
// unfortunately, we can't even listen to the load event of the bugged popup
// so come back to an ugly timeout...
setTimeout(tryToPrint, 200);
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mffvp22u/)